# Magento upgrade issue 1.8 -> 1.8.1 Can't login admin

Tags: magento, authentication, upgrade

After upgrade to Magento CE 1.8.1 I can't login with my admin-account.
The reset-option is activated and I've changed my password but even then I can't login.

Can someboyd help me maybe it's a (known) Magento 1.8.1 bug?

Comment: please check can you able to login into the customer account ? in frontend

Comment: you able to access your magento database?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a cache-problem of the browser and NOT Magento. After restarting the browser I can login. Thanks everybody the problem is solved now !